# API to create an appointment on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there an API or TaskLauncher to create calendar appointments/tasks in WP7 Mango?  I see that there is now readonly access to appointments, but how can I programatically create new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add new appointments through a third-party application (using the public SDK). Appointment aggregation (listing) is pretty much the extent of its integration with your application.

Comment: Any idea if there are plans to add this, maybe with a Task Launcher?

Comment: The Mango SDK API is locked - ready for production and will not change its capabilities with the final release. This functionality might or might not appear in future SDK releases. You can submit your suggestion here: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can control the user's Windows Live calendar and those appointments will show up. There is no API support but it's not hard to capture traffic with Fiddler while you manipulate the calendar using the Windows Live Mail client. This is how I reverse engineered the SkyDrive interface for direct control not involving a browser. I can help you with getting a WL token if you like.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm more curious about adding appointments that will sync with Exchange.  Do you think the same approach of watching the traffic with Fiddler would work?

Comment: Outlook Web Access is WebDAV based like WL but this would depend on Exchange and IIS being set up for OWA.